# File provider - Files not accessible even in the own app

Tags: android, pdf, imageview, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

I am implementing a [File Provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), followed the doc carefully but unable to use the files in the app itself or share any file.

Added manifest, created xml file for dir sharing, generating content uri, granting uri permission, tried sharing files with cache, external, internal dir but nothing is working.

Searched the net but found nothing which is missing in the code.

Below is the code:

**Manifest:**

```
 <provider
     android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
     android:authorities="package.widget.fileprovider"
     android:exported="false"
     android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
     <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
         android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
  </provider>
```

**filepaths.xml**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="widgetDoc" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**GetUri:**

```
private Uri getFileUri(Context context, String name){
        File newFile = new File(context.getCacheDir() + File.separator + StorageUtil.INTERNAL_DIR, name);
        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "package.widget.fileprovider", newFile);       

        return contentUri;
    }
```

**Code to access pdf file:**

```
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = getFileUri(getApplicationContext(), file);
target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
target.setDataAndType(uri,"application/pdf");
Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Choose Pdf Viewer...");
startActivity(intent);
```

**Code to access image:**

```
imageview.setImageURI(getFileUri(getApplicationContext(), file));
```

Kindly help me out where I am going wrong, not even able to use these files in my own app too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never use concatenation to create file paths. Use the proper `File` constructor. Beyond that, what do your `Uri` values that you get from `getFileUri()` look like when you log them to LogCat or look at them in the debugger?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry for late response. I tried both concatenation and without concatenation. Uri is coming like this for image: content://com.android.sample.widget.fileprovider/sample/sample/%0A20140707%20-%20Sample.jpg

Comment: Strongly consider getting rid of the spaces from the filename.

Comment: Removed space but still the same issue: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://com.android.sample.widget.fileprovider/sample/sample/%0AVineet_Shukla_ad.jpg

Comment: Get rid of the linefeed in your filename (`%0A`).

Comment: There is no line feed in the filename, I don't understand from where it is coming.

Comment: Removed linefeed and again the same error: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://com.android.sample.widget.fileprovider/sample/sample/resume_ad.jpg

Comment: @CommonsWare Found the root cause: FTP download had the issues in saving the file correctly. Now there is another issue. I need to show these image files in a widget and now if am accessing the image files from the widget then it is giving IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root however it is working fine with activity.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to show these image files in a widget and now if am accessing the image files from the widget then it is giving IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root however it is working fine with activity

Ideally, use `setImageViewBitmap()`, and make sure that your image is small (under 1MB in heap space, such as less than 512x512).

While the `RemoteViews` can accept a `Uri`, you have good way of associating `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` with a `RemoteViews` for the purposes of populating an `ImageView`. And, you cannot export your `FileProvider`, as `FileProvider` does not allow that.

You can attempt to identify the user's chosen home screen and [use `grantUriPermission()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#grantUriPermission%28java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri,%20int%29) to grant the home screen access to this `Uri`, but I would expect that solution to be fragile.

Comment: Within remoteview, it is not even letting open pdf file on click event however it got flag FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION.

Comment: @VineetShukla: I would recommend that you open up a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide the code where you configure your `PendingIntent` that you use with the `RemoteViews` for the app widget.